# result calculated by Javascript function and displayed in another textbox ->does not instantly come up when I open the web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I created 3 Javascript functions to perform calculations and show result in 3 textboxes , When I save this page and reopen it ->it does not pull the calculated values in respective text boxes unless I move my mouse over them or click on them.
I have used window.onload method with the intention that it will run the function as the page opens.
I am using onKeyUp and onMouseMove event Listeners , maybe that is the cause of the issue. If so, which event listener should I use to perform the operation.

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Admin Fee(5% of Total Amount of FNLCP Funding Used) ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  
                    @Html.TextBox("AdminFeeWorkPlan", "", "{0:c}", new { @class = "form-control", id = "calculateAdminFee", @onKeyUp = "findTotal", @onMouseMove = "findTotal()" })
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        function AdminFeee() {
                            var pullValue = document.getElementById('res').value || "0";

                            var output = (5/100) * parseFloat(pullValue);

                            if (!isNaN(output)) {
                                document.getElementById('calculateAdminFee').value = output;

                            }
                        }
                        window.onload = AdminFeee();

                    </script>

                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group">
       @Html.Label("Total ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                   
 @Html.TextBox("FinalTotal", "", "{0:c}", new { @readonly="readonly", @class = "form-control", id = "calculateTotal" })
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                       function findTotal() {
                            var one = document.getElementById('res').value || "0";
                           
                            var two = document.getElementById('calculateAdminFee').value || "0";
                            var output2 =  parseFloat(one)-parseFloat(two) ;

                            if (!isNaN(output2)) {
                                document.getElementById('calculateTotal').value = output2;
                            }
                        }
                        window.onload = findTotal();

                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `window.onload = findTotal()` replaces the `window.onload` event handler with the result of calling `findTotal()`, which is undefined, since you don't return anything. If you want many things to run onload, use `window.addEventListener('load', findTotal)`. Use similar `addEventListener` methods to add the listeners to the `keyup` or other events.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you so much . It is exactly what I was looking for. :)